# HTTP method POST is not supported by this URL on JBOSS

Tags: java, azure, jboss, active-directory, struts-1

We have to setup MS azure active directory authentication for one of our legacy application which is on Struts-1, will run on JBOSS EAP-7.

The basic setup is like this. We have a welcome file called index.html as below.

```
<html>
 <head>
  <title>TITLE</title>
 </head>
 <FRAMESET border=0 name=fs_rep ROWS="18%,*">
  <FRAME SRC="heading.html" NAME="HEADING">
  <FRAME SRC="logon.jsp" NAME="DISPLAY">
 </FRAMESET>
 <NOFRAMES>
  This browser does not support frames. The application cannot be displayed.
</NOFRAMES>
</html>
```

When the application starts user sees the login page,  gives the credentials and the request goes to LoginAction class which does the LDAP verification.

We are following this link 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-devquickstarts-webapp-java  for setting up MS AD Authetication.

We have created a basic filter in web.xml as

```
<filter-name>BasicFilter</filter-name>
<url-pattern>/index.html</url-pattern>
```

This filter has code for authentication and redirects user to Azure login page. We have given the "Response URL" in azure as: http://localhost:8001/MyApp/index.html

This setup works fine with Weblogic server, but when I try to deploy the same on JBOSS EAP-7, it takes us to MS Azure signup page, we give credentials, the basic filter runs, and finally it shows "**HTTP method POST is not supported by this URL**" in the browser.

Are we on wrong track? How is POST to be supported for the URL (happens only in JBOSS)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that HTTP method `POST` for `.html` file is not supported default on JBoss which is different from other servlet engines.

Per my experience, I think there are some way to solve the issue.

1. It seems like a security constraint on JBoss which may be changed via try to set the below configuration in the `web.xml` file of your project.

   ```
   <security-constraint>    
     <display-name>Example Security Constraint</display-name>    
     <web-resource-collection>    
        <web-resource-name>Protected Area</web-resource-name>    
        <url-pattern>/index.html</url-pattern>   
        <http-method>GET</http-method>    
        <http-method>POST</http-method>  
     </web-resource-collection>
   </security-constraint>
   ```
2. As a work around, you can try to rename your `index.html` to `index.jsp`. This will compile your HTML as a JSP run on JBoss serlvet container, and a JSP always uses the `service()` method and this should avoid the issue on JBoss.

Comment: You saved my day!!  Thank you!!  I went with 2nd approach for now. Working fine.